# Replicate Averageifs in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, average

I am new to Python Pandas and I am trying to replicate Averageifs in pandas but so far what I have found is this:

```
i = 0

id =cal.iloc[i][9]
dis = cal.iloc[i][11]

ind.rename(columns={'Race Distance':'RaceDistance'}, inplace= True)
bench.rename(columns={'Race Distance':'RaceDistance'}, inplace= True)

DISI = (ind.query('HorseIDGet == @id & RaceDistance == @dis').mean(axis=0,numeric_only=True))
DISW = (bench.query('RaceDistance == @dis').mean(axis=0,numeric_only=True))

ind.rename(columns={'RaceDistance':'Race Distance'}, inplace= True)
bench.rename(columns={'RaceDistance':'Race Distance'}, inplace= True)
```

This code is good for one row of the table but I want to get the average of all the rows and Columns in Cal table. [like excel =AVERAGEIFS(average_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, ...)]

I hope I was able to explain what I want. Ask questions for further explanation.

Comment: If you don't mind, please also include a sample data and a desired output in your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation doesn't behave 100% like Excel's AVERAGEIFS function, but it can emulate the most common use-case for AVERAGEIFS:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Iterable
import pandas as pd


def average_ifs(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    avg_cols: str | list[str],
    *criterias: str,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Calculate the average of the values in a column, based on a set of  criterias.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        The dataframe to be processed.
    avg_cols : str | list[str]
        The column(s) to be averaged.
    *criterias : str
        The criteria(s) to be used.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        The dataframe with the average values.

    Notes
    -----
    Function tries to simulate Excel's AVERAGEIFS function.
    """
    groupby_cols = [criteria for criteria in criterias if criteria in df.columns]
    if isinstance(avg_cols, str):
        avg_cols = [avg_cols]
    elif not isinstance(avg_cols, Iterable):
        raise ValueError(f'`avg_cols` accepts only iterable objects, not {type(avg_cols)}')
    groupby_df = df.groupby(groupby_cols, as_index=False).agg(
        {col: 'mean' for col in avg_cols if col in df.columns}
    )
    groupby_df.rename(
        columns={
            col: f'AVERAGEIF({col})' for col in groupby_df.columns.difference(groupby_cols)
        }, inplace=True
    )
    return df.merge(groupby_df, on=groupby_cols)


# === Example ====================================================

example_dict = {
    'COL A': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'COL B': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'],
    'COL C': ['I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'I', 'J', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'I'],
    'VALUE': [5, 10, 25, 3, 8, 9, 12, 14, 13, 33, 21, 78, 91, 5, 7],
    'AVGIFS': [7.5, 7.5, 14.0, 14.0, 10.5, 11.67, 11.67, 11.67, 10.5, 51.75, 14.0, 51.75, 51.75, 51.75, 14.0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(example_dict)

# Column "AVGIFS" calculated using AVERAGEIFS inside EXCEL,
# using the following formula: `=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,C:C,C2,B:B,B2,A:A,A2)`
# The formula calculates the average of the `VALUE` column, with
# columns 'COL A', 'COL B', and 'COL C' as criteria ranges.

# Checking `average_ifs` implementation
res = average_ifs(df, 'VALUE', 'COL A', 'COL B', 'COL C')
print(res)
#
# Prints:
# 
#    COL A COL B COL C  VALUE  AVGIFS  AVERAGEIF(VALUE)
# 0      A     X     I      5    7.50              7.50
# 1      A     X     I     10    7.50              7.50
# 2      A     X     J     25   14.00             14.00
# 3      A     X     J      3   14.00             14.00
# 4      B     Y     I      8   10.50             10.50
# 5      B     Y     I     13   10.50             10.50
# 6      B     Y     J      9   11.67             11.67
# 7      B     Y     J     12   11.67             11.67
# 8      B     Y     J     14   11.67             11.67
# 9      C     Z     J     33   51.75             51.75
# 10     C     Z     J     78   51.75             51.75
# 11     C     Z     J     91   51.75             51.75
# 12     C     Z     J      5   51.75             51.75
# 13     C     Z     I     21   14.00             14.00
# 14     C     Z     I      7   14.00             14.00
```

This implementation works the same way as the `AVERAGEIFS` for cases like the one below:

[image: Excel AVERAGEIFS example]

It also supports the specification of multiple columns to compute the average, like so:

```py
#                             ^---- Columns to calculate the average
#                             |
#                     +-------+---------+
#                     |                 |
res = average_ifs(df, ['VALUE', 'VALUE2'], 'COL A', 'COL B', 'COL C')
#                                        |                          |
#                                        +--------------+-----------+
#                                                       |
#                  Columns to simulate the criteria ----v
#                  ranges from Excel
```

Comment: Thanks Ingwersen, this seems to work but what if I want to do something like this below excel formula, how can I change this code?

=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$6,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6,Sheet1!C2)

Comment: Hi @RafiUrRehman I'm not sure I've understood your question. Are you referring to the function syntax (how you're supposed to use the function), and how to make it look more like its Excel counterpart, or are you referring to some specific functionality of Excel AVERAGEIFS? If it's the latter, could provide further details? As for making it look more like the AVERAGEIFS from excel, there's no easy way of doing it. You could change the parameter `*criterias` from the average_ifs to instead be able to pass a bunch of dataframe masks, but I don't know how it would make it more like Excel.

Comment: thanks for replying. Basically what I am trying to ask is how can I use this code with two data frames. 

Sorry, I am new to pandas so don't mind if I am asking for something that you have already explained in the code. TY

Comment: @RafiUrRehman no problem! Wouldn't it be possible to combine both dataframes together before calling the function? You can use the `merge` method from dataframe, that in some ways works similarly to `VLOOKUP` here's the link to an introductory guide of pandas merge/join: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index

Comment: @RafiUrRehman the code, given your example of two tables would look like something similar to this:

 ```df_combined = df1.merge(df2, on=[<LIST OF KEY COLUMNS>], how=<'inner', 'left', 'right', or 'outer'>)
res = average_ifs(df_combined , 'COLUMN NAME TO PERFORM AVG', 'CRITERIA RANGE 1 COLUMN NAME', ...)
```
im